# Use sqlite with php/adodb

Tags: php, sqlite, adodb

I'm trying to connect to a sqlite3 database using ADOdb. Using:

- pdo_sqlite: works
- sqlite3:

  > Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to open database: unable to open database file'
- sqlite:

  > Could not connect to database

```php
$driver = "pdo_sqlite";
$db = NewADOConnection("$driver://".urlencode(dirname(__FILE__)."/test.db3"));
if (!$db) {
  die("Could not connect to database");
}
```

**edit**

I also asked the question on adodb's forums: http://phplens.com/lens/lensforum/msgs.php?id=19236

Comment: FYI: you really should use 4 spaces or ` to highlight code instead of doing crazy html on your own.

Comment: Why don't you just use a builtin abstraction like `SQLite3`, or `PDO_SQLite`?

Comment: Because I'm building a web framework and I want to support sqlite and mysql. Also using database functions directly is not abstraction.

Comment: Also ADOdb offers many usefull (tested) features like ActiveRecords and Datadict (to create and modify tables on the fly in a general sql dialect). http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-active-record.htm http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-datadict.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited `drivers/adodb-sqlite3.inc.php`. Function _connect()

```
if (empty($argHostname) && $argDatabasename) $argHostname = $argDatabasename;
$this->_connectionID = new SQLite3($argHostname); // hack
if ($this->_connectionID === false) return false;
$this->_createFunctions();      
return true;
```

seems to work with my little test (active record: new item, save, reload it, delete).